Is data set enough for regression analysis?
I need to conduct regression analysis for my thesis (panel data), however, my data set turned out to be really small. I have only 6 companies to study (annual data for 11 years) and the sector i am looking into literally consists of like 7 companies. Can you please explain why 6 companies are not enough for such regression? Or maybe you have useful sources for me to read.
